# C++ MFC Keyboard Accelerators

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a `CWinAppEx` derived class and a `CFrameWndEx` derived class but I cannot for the life of me understand how to use keyboard accelerators.

I have an accelerator table with an accelerator:

```
ID:       ID_CLOSE_FOCUSED_WINDOW
Modifier: Ctrl
Key:      W
Type:     VIRTKEY
```

I have this line in the message map of my `CFrameWndEx` derived class:

```
ON_COMMAND(ID_CLOSE_FOCUSED_WINDOW, CloseLastFocusedWindow)
```

I have tried overriding `PreTranslateMessage` in the `CFrameWndEx` derived class and inside `PreTranslateMessage` calling `TranslateAccelerators` but I still don't receive a command that is the same as the ID in the accelerator table - not hitting a breakpoint in the `CloseLastFocusedWindow` function.

Anyone able to shed some light? I feel like I am following the documentation correctly but it is not working for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that the resource-id of the accelerator (e.g.: `IDR_MAINFRAME`) ahould match the resource-id used to load the frame

Comment: Thanks Edward, my resource id matches the id used to load the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Couple thoughts. Are you sure that CloseLastFocusedWindow has the correct signature?

Should be equivalent of:

```
afx_msg void CloseLastFocusedWindow();
```

Also, does DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP() appear prior to the above declaration?

I think CFrameWndEx will call TranslateAccelerator for you by default. Generally you'll only need to be concerned with LoadAccelerators and TranslateAccelerator in places that don't process them automatically (e.g. dialog window, etc.).

**EDIT**

Also note that the means of frame construction matters. For example, if you construct a frame window via CSingleDocTemplate, then the first parameter passed into the CSingleDocTemplate constructor will control which accelerator table is loaded.

Example:

```
CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView));
```

In the code above, the IDR_MAINFRAME accelerator table will be loaded and any required accelerators should be entered there.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply. 
CloseLastFocusedWindow has that exact signature, including the afx_msg. And the message map is also correctly formed - I am using it to catch many other command messages. 

I wondered if it would call TranslateAccelerator for me, as it definitely does call LoadAccelerators (Asserts if I call LoadAccelerators myself because it is more than one call to the function).

Comment: How are you creating the frame window?

Comment: I updated my answer to discuss frame window construction considerations. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately, IDR_MAINFRAME is the resource ID and I have LoadFrame(IDR_MAINFRAME, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | FWS_ADDTOTITLE, NULL, NULL); to load the CFrameWndEx class.

Answer (score 0):

I was now experiencing a similar problem: Apart of the default view (the one spcified in CSingleDocTemplate) I've created another one in a non-standard way. After processing the Ctrl+W combination for closing the non-standard view, the main menu ceased to work. It then turned out that I was forgetting to set a new active view. As a side effect of this, the document didn't receive any commands, e.g. from the mentioned main menu.

So my advice is: when you're closing a (non-standardly created) view, don't forget to call `CFrameWnd::SetActiveView`.